# How to refresh a div to load new record when theres new record in Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in a page where I show a list of records which are stored in my Database ( firebase). Whenever there is a new record in the database, I want the div to auto load in the new record without refreshing the whole page. So how can I do that?

Javascript code on showing records

```
                query.on("child_added", function(messageSnapshot) {

                var keys = Object.keys(messageSnapshot);
                var messageData = messageSnapshot.val();
                var key = messageSnapshot.getKey();
                console.log("key is " + messageSnapshot.getKey());
                console.log("messagesnapshot is " + messageSnapshot);

                var obj = {
                    key: key,

                };
                arr.push(obj);

                ref.child(key + "/User Information").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                    var name = snapshot.val().firstName

                    s = "<li><a href='#'>" + no + '. ' + name + ' ' + key + "</a></li>";
                    no++;

                   sources.push(s);

                    //  for ( property in messageSnapshot) {
                    //   console.log( property ); // Outputs: foo, fiz or fiz, foo
                    //}

                    console.log("arr.length is " + arr.length);
                }).then(function(pagination) {
                    Pagination();

                });

            });

    function Pagination() {
        var arrLength = arr.length;
        var container = $("#mylist");
        //            var sources = function () {
        //                var result = [];
        //
        //                for (var i = 1; i < arrLength; i++) {
        //                    result.push(i);
        //                }
        //
        //                return result;
        //            }();

        var options = {
            dataSource: sources,
            pageSize: 10,
            callback: function(data, pagination) {
                //window.console && console.log(response, pagination);

                var dataHtml = '';

                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    dataHtml += item;
                });




                console.log(dataHtml);
                container.prev().html(dataHtml);
            }
        };


        //$.pagination(container, options);

        container.addHook('beforeInit', function() {
            window.console && console.log('beforeInit...');
        });
        container.pagination(options);


        container.addHook('beforePageOnClick', function() {
            window.console && console.log('beforePageOnClick...');
            //return false
        });

        return container;
    }
```

Html code div

```
   <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
        <button onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
        <h1>Pending Transaction</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="mylist"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

At first your local code must be aware of changes in the Database, so the plain answer is:

Your JS-Code must periodically ask your DB for changes, if changes are available you can call that changes and update your content via an AJAX-Request and put it into the div#mylist

This "periodically ask" is called long polling, aspnet has for example the framework called [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: that is called ajax. and I can't see a need for mentioning ASP.NET and signal R

Comment: Why downvoting my answer? You asking people to code for you? This is called "work" and for "work" you have to pay

Comment: I voted to close the question. _You asking people to code for you?_ I am not the OP. _for "work" you have to pay_ you are in the wrong site. in SO, you won't get payment.

Comment: Firebase api has a function('child_added') that checks for new records added. When there is a new record, there will be a error which basically says that it can retrieve the value of the new record. But when i refreshed the page, the new record will be loaded. So I was thinking maybe if I can just refresh the div, it will work.

Comment: @SagarV "Whenever there is a new record .." this has nothing to do with ajax, ajax is just another method to reach the goal, with this he has to ask every second/minute the database if changes are made, this is not eficient. Because of that i mentioned SignalR, to show him what methods they were using, and what fallbacks are available

Comment: how signal R will help OP if he is not using .NET